# Select Query To Get Data From Database

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables joined called `user` and `records` with the structure below. With query below, i am trying to get users with `status` = 1 who have hours or seconds > 0. When i run the query, it gives me `user 142` who has status 0.

The query actually returns the two rows in the user table. It should return just one row.. i.e user 199

What is wrong with my query please ?

**user**

```
id    status
199    1
142    0
```

**records**

```
user_id  hours  seconds
  199    10      90
  144     0      800
```

**Controller**

```
$results = array();
$results = $this->db->query("SELECT user.id, user.status, records.hours, records.seconds 
                             from user 
                             INNER JOIN records 
                                 ON user.id = records.user_id 
                             WHERE user.status = 1 
                               and records.hours 
                                or records.seconds > 0  ");
$get_results = $results->result_array();
return $get_results;
```

Comment: Not sure about this part: `...and records.hours or records.seconds > 0 ` - I guess you meant `and records.hours > 0 or records.seconds > 0 ` or maybe `and (records.hours > 0 or records.seconds > 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

user brackets in between OR condition

```
$results = array();
$results = $this->db->query("SELECT user.id,user.status,records.hours,records.seconds 
                             FROM user 
                             INNER JOIN records 
                                 ON user.id = records.user_id 
                             WHERE user.status = 1 
                               AND (records.hours > 0 OR records.seconds > 0)");
$get_results = $results->result_array();
return $get_results;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...That worked. I will accept this answer